# jQuery "$(...).effect is not a function"

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, effect

I searched through the forum already but I can't find any way to fix the problem I have with the "effect" function in jQuery.

I get exactly the error `TypeError: $(...).effect is not a function` in the code :

```
$('div.step').removeClass('active');
$("div.step").effect('slide', {direction: 'right', mode: 'hide'}, 500);
$('#step' + step + '').addClass('active');
$('#step' + step + '').effect('slide', {direction: 'right', mode: 'show'}, 500);
```

I included both jQuery and jQuery UI like this in `<head></head>` :

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

But in vain, do you have any idea? Thank you

Comment: Can you reproduce this in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: do you have any other plugins included?

Comment: This is the jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/gYP9m/
Except a datepicker triggered by some `$().fdatepicker()...` in the same `document.ready` I don't have any other plugin included. Thank you

Comment: I had the same problem and fixed it by using only one jquery lib. so dont overwrite it

Answer (score 11):

You need to put your custom script after your jQuery and jQuery UI declarations, and wrap it within a document `ready()` function:

```
<body>
    ...
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            ...
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: That is what I do, check the jsfiddle above to see what I coded. Thank you

Comment: @mentinet you haven't included jQuery UI in your JSFiddle example. It works fine with it: http://jsfiddle.net/JamesD/gYP9m/1.

Comment: Ok I can see it. But the code is exactly like mine and I include the jQuery UI...although it doesn't work on my machine. 
How did you include the jQuery UI on jsfiddle ?

Comment: Click on External Resources in the sidebar and paste in the URL.

Comment: Ok thank, it works. Although, I still can't make it work on my machine. I tried putting the `$(document).Ready()`in the `head` as well (I had it in my footer file) but still not working.

Answer (score 8):

I do not know if the problem was solved but I found a way to replicate the shake function with the animation function and it works like a charm:

```js
function shake() {
        var div = document.getElementById('yourElementID');
        var interval = 100;
        var distance = 10;
        var times = 4;

        $(div).css('position', 'relative');

        for (var iter = 0; iter < (times + 1) ; iter++) {
            $(div).animate({
                left: ((iter % 2 == 0 ? distance : distance * -1))
            }, interval);
        }                                                                                                          
        $(div).animate({ left: 0 }, interval);
    }
```

This solution belongs to [thisSite](http://bradleyhamilton.com/projects/shake/index.html), all credits to them.
I hope this will be useful to someone in the future, if so please mark it as solution, greetings.

Answer (score 7):

Add jQueryUI not just jQuery. jQuery doesn't contain the `effect()` function:
https://code.jquery.com/ui

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('div.step').removeClass('active');
    $("div.step").effect('slide', {direction: 'right', mode: 'hide'}, 500);
    $('#step' + step + '').addClass('active');
    $('#step' + step + '').effect('slide', {direction: 'right', mode: 'show'}, 500);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, it turned out that my project was using a "Custom download" version of Jquery-UI which had been set to exclude the `effects` plugin. Replacing my version of Jquery UI with a full version fixed my issue.