# Auto play slider content jquery

Tags: jquery, slider

I need to create one line slider to rotate list of h3 automatically.

I have created wrapper, and inner elements. Now i have a function to show one element, hide all another. After delay i try to catch next element, and show it.

I try to

```js
(function($) {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    function context(obj, func) {
      return function() {
        func(obj);
      }
    };
    var bestNews = {
      i: 0,
      init: function(id) {
        this.items = $(id);
        this.item = this.items[this.i];
        return this;
      },
      run: function() {
        var next = context({
          obj: this
        }, function(data) {
          data.obj.i++;
          if (data.obj.i >= data.obj.items.length) {
            data.obj.i = 0;
          }
          data.obj.item = data.obj.items[data.obj.i];

          var next_run = context({
            obj: data.obj
          }, function(data) {
            data.obj.run();
          });
          $(data.obj.item).show('drop', {
            direction: 'left'
          }, 1000, next_run);
        });
        $(this.item).delay(6000).effect('drop', {
          direction: 'right'
        }, 1000, next);
      }
    }
    bestNews.init('.slideshoww h3').run();

  });
})(jQuery);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="slideshoww">
  <h3>Text 1</h3>
  <h3>Text 2</h3>
  <h3>Text 3</h3>
</div>
```

But have error...

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).delay(...).effect is not a function

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery "$(...).effect is not a function"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21991062/jquery-effect-is-not-a-function)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`.effect()`](http://api.jqueryui.com/effect/) is a function of [`jquery ui`](https://jqueryui.com/), you have to include it in your project

> `.effect()` [.effect( effect [, options ] [, duration ] [, complete ] )]
>
> **Description**: *Apply an animation effect to an element.*
>
> Returns: **jQuery object**

Here are a working snippet with the good version of `jQuery-ui` :

```js
(function($) {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    function context(obj, func) {
      return function() {
        func(obj);
      }
    };
    var bestNews = {
      i: 0,
      init: function(id) {
        this.items = $(id);
        this.item = this.items[this.i];
        return this;
      },
      run: function() {
        var next = context({
          obj: this
        }, function(data) {
          data.obj.i++;
          if (data.obj.i >= data.obj.items.length) {
            data.obj.i = 0;
          }
          data.obj.item = data.obj.items[data.obj.i];

          var next_run = context({
            obj: data.obj
          }, function(data) {
            data.obj.run();
          });
          $(data.obj.item).show('drop', {
            direction: 'left'
          }, 1000, next_run);
        });
        $(this.item).delay(6000).effect('drop', {
          direction: 'right'
        }, 1000, next);
      }
    }
    bestNews.init('.slideshoww h3').run();

  });
})(jQuery);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<div class="slideshoww">
  <h3>Text 1</h3>
  <h3>Text 2</h3>
  <h3>Text 3</h3>
</div>
```